# How can I add Unicode 8 support to Emacs 24.3?

Tags: unicode

`insert-char` provides a very convenient way to enter Unicode code points using their names and even search for code point names.  Unfortunately, GNU Emacs 24.3 and Unicode 8 were released at roughly the same time, so the new code points are not available from the list provided by `insert-char`.  How can I add them?

**UPDATE**

I implemented [Aaron's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2162/aaron-miller) solution (albeit in a lazy manner) and it works.  I used the emoji list from http://emojipedia.org/unicode-7.0/ and http://emojipedia.org/unicode-8.0/ (Emacs 24.3 lacks the Unicode 7 code points too, by the way)

```
(ucs-names)
(nconc ucs-names
       '(("SLIGHTLY SMILING FACE" . ?)
         ("SLIGHTLY FROWNING FACE" . ?)
         ("SLEUTH OR SPY" . ?)
         ("SPEAKING HEAD IN SILHOUETTE" . ?)
         ("MAN IN BUSINESS SUIT LEVITATING" . ?)
         ("REVERSED HAND WITH MIDDLE FINGER EXTENDED" . ?)
         ("RAISED HAND WITH PART BETWEEN MIDDLE AND RING FINGERS" . ?)
         ("RAISED HAND WITH FINGERS SPLAYED" . ?)
         ("EYE" . ?)
         ("HOLE" . ?)
         ;; and so on
           ))
```

Comment: Note the current stable emacs is 24.5. There is a development version number 25 which seems to include the unicode 8.0 support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names and code points used by `insert-char` come from the value of `ucs-names`, which is a (very long) alist of Unicode names and code points originating ultimately from C code. This list isn't populated during init, because doing so can take a little while, but during the first call to the function `(ucs-names)`.

If all you want to do is make Unicode 8 code points available in `insert-char`, you should be able to do so by manually adding them to `ucs-names` *after* calling `(ucs-names)` once to populate it. (If `ucs-names` is non-nil when that first call occurs, the function will assume that what's there is what should be there, and won't add anything - so whatever you added will be all you have available. This probably will break a lot of things, so you'll want to ensure it doesn't happen.)

Since `ucs-names` is an alist, you can just `push` into it; its members are of form `("CODE POINT NAME" . <code point>)`, where **code point** is the decimal representation. For example:

`(push '("BOTTLE WITH POPPING CORK" . 127870) ucs-names)`

would make available in `insert-char` an emoji which presumably would be useful for, I don't know, chatting about a wedding or the christening of a ship or something. Whether it'll show up in your buffers as an emoji, or in the same form Emacs uses to represent any other un-renderable character, is a different question; if you use a fontset including a font with that code point defined, it should render, but I can't be certain of that because I don't actually have such a font.

Looking at [emojify](https://github.com/iqbalansari/emacs-emojify), which uses images to display emoji in Emacs installations without an emoji font available, it appears to include BOTTLE WITH POPPING CORK, and I would expect it to be correctly displayed. Unfortunately, emojify 0.3 from Melpa Stable appears to be broken, or at least it's broken on my machine, so I can't say for certain there either. It's definitely worth a shot, though.

Comment: Cool! It works.

Comment: I've downloaded the symbols block package from http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/ to see corks popping  . I copied the .ttf files to `~/.fonts` and run `fc-cache -fv`

Comment: No need to convert the code points to decimal, if you have them as hex (as I think is more common with unicode): The example in the answer could just as well be written `(push '("BOTTLE WITH POPPING CORK" . #x1F37E) ucs-names)`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You don't have to use the hexadecimal representation either. This works too `("BOTTLE WITH POPPING CORK" . ?)`  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html